# Angularjs checkbox value does not uncheck when ng-model associated with it, is false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<ul class="quiz-footer">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Glossar</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Suche</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Lesezeichen</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item">Frage:</li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><<</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" ng-click="decrementOne()"><</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" ng-click="incrementOne()">></a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">>></a></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" ng-click="statusChange()" ng-model='statusBox.isChecked' ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">nur unbeantwortete</li>
            <li><a class="nav-link weiter-link quiz-anzeigen">Lösung anzeigen</a></li>
</ul>
```

When user clicks on the checkbox it should trigger the click event to some update. Then, I want checkbox to go back to its normal state (unchecked state).

```
app.controller("QuizController", ['total', '$scope', '$http', function (total, $scope, $http) {
    $scope.statusBox= { isChecked: false };

$scope.statusChange = function () {
        $scope.quizzes[$scope.count].exclude= true;
        $scope.statusBox.isChecked = "YES";
        $scope.incrementOne();
    }

    $scope.excludeQuestion = function () {
    }

    $scope.incrementOne = function () {
        $scope.disableStatus = false    ;
            $scope.selection = [];
            $scope.three = "front";
            $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
        $scope.statusBox.isChecked = false;
    }
}]);
```

The value of $scope.statusChecked.isChecked becomes true but it does not uncheck the checkbox.

Can anyone here please help me?

Comment: I won't put up a separate answer for this but your `$scope.quizzes[$scope.count].exclude= true;` gives an error and the `$scope.incrementOne();` function is not even fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $scope.statusBox= { isChecked: false };

   <li><input type="checkbox" ng-click="statusChange()" ng-model='statusBox.isChecked' ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">nur unbeantwortete</li>

     $scope.statusChange = function () {
        $scope.quizzes[$scope.count].exclude= true;
        $scope.statusBox.isChecked = "YES";
        $scope.incrementOne();
    }
```

You said that ng-true-value = true , but when statusChange function it's change for "YES" value is not "true" value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-checked`.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="statusChange()" ng-checked='statusBox.isChecked' ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">nur unbeantwortete</li>
```

It will checked for truthy value and unchecked for falsy value.

[See doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

Comment: When I changed to ng-checked it does not updated everytime.